# Trying to create so many .dat files using loop

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, awk, ksh

My requirement is to create files in the respective directory (existing) in the server.

```
#!/bin/ksh
file1=$1 # Signifies DATE config file    
file2=$2 # Signifies MONT config file    
file4=$3 # Signifies SEQN config file    
config1=`cat $file1 | awk -F "," '{print $1}'`    
config2=`cat $file2 | awk -F "," '{print $2}'`    
config3=`cat $file3 | awk -F "," '{print $3}'`    
echo AT_EXTENSION_"$config1""$config2""$config3".dat    
cat MY_DIR/$echo
```

Will this KornShell (ksh) script work to create a file in the respective directory with the contents in echo?

Comment: (I am not the downvoter.) I think you need to clarify what data is supposed to be put into the file and where the filename is coming from.

Comment: Yes, please clarify what your expected outcome would be and what you've already tried (that hasn't worked).

Comment: What should be the contents of the `.dat` files?

Comment: Or what should be the names of the files? Should the names be constructed from the config files, or should the contents of the files come from the config files?

Comment: The content should come from config files.

Comment: Ok. Should there be one file per row in the config files, and what should in that case the names of the files be?

Answer (score 1):

As the question currently stands, it appears that you want to write the contents of files `$file1`, `$file2`, and `$file3` into a file called `AT_EXTENSION_"$config1""$config2""$config3".dat`.  If this is the case, then do:

```
cat "$file1" "$file2" "$file3" >AT_EXTENSION_"$config1""$config2""$config3".dat
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to not use `cat` with `awk` and you should change back tics to parentheses `$(code)` and also add double quote around the variable name, to make sure file is read correctly
Not like this:

```
config1=`cat $file1 | awk -F "," '{print $1}'`
```

But like this:

```
config1=$(awk -F "," '{print $1}' "$file1")
```